# Tunnel to heroku database?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've got a django project on heroku and it uses postgre database on heroku (ec2). It all works fine, but on one computer I don't have access to postger port 5432 so I need to setup a tunnel from my computer to there. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have some sort of access to an intermediate host to make it possible. Heroku does not support it out of the box.

[Corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) does SSH over HTTP proxy. Then you can open a transparent proxy like [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/). This way you don't necessarily have to know about the firewall.

This all applies to Linux and possibly Mac. On Windows you can pipe your connection through Putty.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I use ssh tunneling over an intermediary server.